Everyday relevance of theory of relativity
I hope my question is not completely off-topic here. I'm looking for arguments in favor of scientific curiosity and I'm struggling to justify theories of relativity. I'm happy that politicians fund basic research into cosmology; I just don't know how scientists manage to convince them to fund it.
I can understand the argument for quantum mechanics. To my understanding, its discovery has had a profound influence on our everyday lives: No QM $\rightarrow$ no microelectronics $\rightarrow$ no computers (as we know them today), and I wouldn't be writing my question here. And, I guess, QM has also influenced chemistry, medical diagnostics (MRI?), and probably many more.
I'm also aware that SR and GR have had a tremendous impact on "our" (meaning: the scientists') understanding of the universe, its past, its current state, and its future. But I doubt their influence on our everyday lives is nearly as revolutionary as quantum mechanics'. OK, without having discovered relativity we wouldn't have nuclear power or mutually assured destruction, and we'd be wondering why our GPS clocks are off by fractions of a second and why Mercury's path around the Sun is not an ellipse. But, apart from that, we could have all the amenities as we do now, right? So, are theories of relativity, regarding their relevance to our everyday lives, just like ancient philology or art history, only ivory tower pass-times?

This is a good question, but I'm not sure it's on topic for the site. As a comment I will note that QM and GR weren't invented/discovered specifically to create either microelectronics or GPS - those were fortuitous side effects (I should note there are people who claim the academic study of QM had little to no impact on the development of e.g. the transistor - I think they're wrong, but it's a viewpoint people have). In general you can't know what the impact of research will be on technology or society before hand. Also: I think you underestimate the impact of GPS.

Seems you apply double standards,- for the computers can be also created without no knowledge about electronics, QM and similar (mechanical computers, hydraulic computers, etc). If you accept that without QM we would not have modern-day electronic computers, then you must accept too that without relativity we would not have modern-day GPS devices, because knowledge of relativity greatly increases accuracy of GPS signal. This reflects on position measurement accuracy, because for triangulation you need synchronized signals in time.

@AgniusVasiliauskas I'm sorry if it came across that way. I'm aware of the computers you mention and I also think vacuum-tube computers would be possible without QM. I just think that they would be slow, big, expensive, and consume so much energy, that sites like stackexchange wouldn't be viable.

@IgorF. Same fact about GPS,- without relativity GPS position detection accuracy would drop considerably. If you accept this, then you must acknowledge relativity influence on modern day devices as you do for QM. Otherwise - your thinking is pretty much double-standard.

Also I feel that you underestimate the role of cosmology, cosmos research overall for the  impact on everyday life. Are you happy laying on the soft bed mattress based on memory foam ? Then you should know that it is invented by NASA for keeping it's astronauts safe and comfortable during flights.

@AgniusVasiliauskas I think you are being too confrontational and towards a wrong target. Can you perhaps post an answer which I could use to convince---not alienate!---a non-scientist? Regarding GPS accuracy, I addressed that in my comments below two answers. Space research is not necessarily cosmology and I'm not sure about the importance of memory foam...

To be perfectly honest, I'm not sure relativity is directly relevant for everyday life. Particularly GR. Someone who only cares about science for its practical applications might not see relativity as worth funding.

Re, "without having discovered relativity we wouldn't have nuclear power" That's a strange thing to say. How do you connect the theory of relativity to the discovery of neutrons and nuclear chain reactions?

The global financial system is highly dependent on timing of signals in copper and fiber optic cables, that travel at light speed in the medium. I have to imagine SR effects come into play in the design

Art history and philology are important.

@RC_23, It's true, the design of modern computers and computer networks depends very much on accounting for the speed of light. But relativity? Not so much. Banks and other financial institutions and their customers and their data centers rarely move relative to each other at any significant fraction of the speed of light.

Also, in theory, a clock should be seen to tick more slowly when it's held right up against a big stack of gold bars, but either the effect is too small to have any impact, or else they are careful to keep their computers and their networking equipment at a safe distance from the gold vaults. (I'm not sure which.)

@IgorF. Without knowledge of GR, the GPS system would be more than off by fractions of a second. It wouldn't work at all. And global comms for GPS and many other things,  communicating amongst cell towers, cables, and satellites all rely on microsecond timing.

I'm not sure why you think nuclear power and the GPS aren't relevant to our everyday lives. How about wireless communication? The special theory of relativity is the logical outcome of taking Maxwell's equations for electromagnetism seriously. The combination of SR and quantum mechanics gives quantum field theory, including quantum electrodynamics, the modern theory of the electromagnetic field that explains things like lasers.

"...aren't relevant" is not what I meant. I wrote "(not) nearly as revolutionary". Nuclear power could be substituted by other sources, maybe at a slightly different price, and GPS could be heuristically corrected, without knowing the cause for the error. What probably had a much bigger influence at the course of history is the MAD doctrine, which required nuclear weapons. But, in my question I was primarily interested in technological development.

The title of the question is "everyday relevance of theory of relativity", and that's what I was referring to.

If you looked up the actual history of the pioneers, you will find that the birth of QM involved a lot of bouncing around between SR and NR viewpoints. It is quite central; even de Broglie's original hypothesis of matter waves was formulated in SR, and then Schrödinger first obtained the SR Klein-Gordon equation, before taking the step back and arriving at Schrödinger equation. Needless to say, Dirac equation needed SR, even if SR QM is not a satisfactory theory.

So, the answer is, "Without SR no QM"? Before posting my question, I looked up Klein-Gordon and Schrödinger and was under the impression that Schördinger could have derived his equation without the relativistic term. This is also what I concluded from his Nobel speech. I wasn't aware of the Dirac-SR connection (I'm not a physicist) - thanks for that.

As important as special and general relativity are (which is pretty much what I do all day), I’ll play devil’s advocate here. I’ll take ‘everyday relevance’ to mean what it meant pre 1900, or even what it what it means today, for day-to-day normie purposes.
For day to day purposes, special (and hence general) relativity doesn’t really matter. Civilization has run perfectly well (ignore all humanitarian issues) without knowing anything about SR. We’ve had wonderful architecture, the industrial revolution, great advances in farming/agriculture, good transportation (cars and ships) etc. All of this only relies on Newtonian mechanics, and Galilean relativity. And of course, Galilean relativity is pretty intuitive, especially you can experience it yourself by sitting at home and bouncing a ball up and down, vs doing the same thing on a car/ship (or even on a horse carriage, assuming the roads aren’t too bumpy).
In fact, even today, as long as I don’t have anything special going on in a lab, my everyday routine doesn’t really rely on SR: wake up, workout, cook (sure, today we have fancy stoves, but you can easily imagine that in many parts of the world, people still use gas stoves), go to school and work, return, etc.
The next thing to consider is electricity and magnetism. This is conceptually, the birth of special relativity (and indeed how Einstein wrote his paper). So, without a deep understanding of SR, one cannot really say they understand E&M. But still, I would argue that this doesn’t come into ‘day to day’ experiences. For instance, Faraday (who had little mathematical background, especially compared to Ampere, Maxwell, Gauss) figured out his flux rule by fiddling around with magnets and circuits. It would only take a few decades to carry this out at the industrial scale, to build electric generators. I doubt the people who were building these things had any knowledge of the depths of special relativity; they were simply following instructions to build a certain contraption in such and such way, and then everyone else enjoyed the fruits of their labour. Granted, these early designs are not as sophisticated, nor as efficient as we have today, but that is to be expected. So, my point is that up until the 1900s, we have had a pretty developed world, and all of this without an inkling of SR.
Next, you mention

I just don't know how scientists manage to convince them to fund it.

And I would say that in the early stages of GR, it was even difficult to get physicists into researching GR and cosmology (a lot of effort was focused on quantum stuff).
Hence, as long as you don’t ask too much (in terms of precision, efficiency, and just innovation in general), SR doesn’t really impact the average Joe. It’s the same idea as how the average person wouldn’t really care about how much engineering prowess goes into making F1 cars over a Toyota, if their purpose is just travelling from point A to B and back, over and over.

In fact, even the GPS calibration stuff, I think is sort of a red-herring, especially if you’re asking for ‘everyday relevance’. I view that as more of an ‘implementation detail’ - yes, the underlying concepts rely on GR, but really who really feels the effect of it ‘working’? We would definitely all experience it when it doesn’t work, but when things are working as expected, it doesn’t really affect us.
This is similar to how while I may be somewhat proficient in coding and basic computer science, I have no clue how Python is created from the ground up. I know some basic commands, and I make it do what I want. Of course, the more you know, the better you can code, but still, I can get by just fine without knowing anything about the internal structure. In fact, these implementation details could very well change in the future, yet at the surface level, us users wouldn’t really feel the difference (perhaps we might need to learn some new commands, or we might find that some old piece of code is deprecated).
In a similar vein, many physicists do not know the rigorous foundations of set theory, yet they’re happy to work mathematically with the consequences (and implicitly use ZFC, or if more conservative, ZF). And to go a step further: in the early days, lots of physicists didn’t know any functional analysis, yet they were satisfied with their (often times suspicious) matrix-type calculations, as long as it matched the corresponding experimental data. So, once again, the deep and far reaching theorems of functional analysis (whose importance cannot be understated) wasn’t really needed/appreciated by the early practioners, hence in their day-to-day experiences, it didn’t really affect them.

Did you realise that fractions of seconds in GPS is equivalent to many kilometers errors? Without taking into account GR and SR our navigation systems would be useless.
I also know of an experiment where very precise time measurement using lasers and glass fibers could determine the difference of altitude between to places in the Netherlands, by using the effect of GR. It was even possible to determine the change in this difference over time.

"Did you realise that fractions of seconds in GPS is equivalent to many kilometers errors?" Sure, but, as I wrote in another comment, I think this error can be heuristically compensated. I am also fascinated by the precision achieved in current experimental physics (think of LIGO); I just don't know how to argue with non-scientists about their practical relevance.

this error can be heuristically compensated Can you give some references for this claim ?

@IgorF., If you need a heuristic to compensate for your failure to account for relativity, then I would say that relativity did, in fact, have some relevance in that situation.

It is only if you go slow and don't call home from another planet that special relativity does not affect you so much.

There is a very deep and intimate connection between the special theory of relativity (i.e. relativity without gravity) and electromagnetism. Admittedly, If we did not understand relativity then we would still be able to use electromagnetic theory to get as far as electricity generation and transformers and things like that. However it is debatable whether one could design and operate high-frequency circuits without a more thorough understanding of electromagnetism, and that would involve an understanding of special relativity. Such circuits are now widely used in computers and information infrastructure throughout the world.
The counter-argument to this suggestion is that you could imagine a set of r.f. engineers with great expertise in r.f. circuit design who never heard of Lorentz transformations and things like that, and who never needed to bother about more than one inertial frame of reference. That is true, but science simply does not work like that. You won't in practice arrive at the more sophisticated stuff (e.g. advanced r.f. circuit design) without someone somewhere noticing the simpler stuff (e.g. Lorentz contraction, time dilation).
Maybe this is just musings on human behaviour, but I hope it may be helpful to the question.

Interesting. I have friends and former colleagues who studied/worked in RF engineering and they never mentioned relativity.  They were much more bothered by the effects of the coast at radio propagation, for which they had no theory...
